# Trying to press a button and toggle an LED flash at 2Hz until i press the button again

Tags: c++, arduino, toggle, led

i'm trying to learn coding and this has really stumped me so i thought i would ask you lovely people.

basically i'm trying to press a button and have an LED toggle on that is flashing on and off twice in a second, this will be continuous until i press the button again that will turn it off.

here is my code so far.

```
bool latch = false;

void setup(){
pinMode(1, INPUT);
pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}
void loop(){
if (digitalRead(1)){
  latch = !latch;
}
if (latch == 1){
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);
  delay(1000);
}else{
  digitalWrite(13, LOW)
}
}
```

Comment: How is the posted code not satisfying your needs?

Comment: it works until i try to press the button again and the LED stays flashing, i have no idea why

Comment: Try indenting your code properly then look at it closely.  Also, for readability choose either 1/0 or true/false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the calls to `delay(1000)`, your code requires you to press the button in the exact split-second instant when `digitalRead(1)` is called. The Arduino cannot listen for button presses while `delay()` is in action. Also, you call `delay(1000)` twice, which flashes the LED on and off once in two seconds, not twice in once second.

The solution is to make a counter that counts how many milliseconds have passed since the last time the LED was toggled on or off. The loop will add 1 to `counter` every millisecond, so that when `counter` is equal to or greater than 500 (half a second), the LED toggles on or off.

Here is a program that starts blinking the LED (on-and-off in 1 second) when the button is pressed, and stops blinking when the button is pressed again. There are more explanations in the code.

```cpp
bool latch = false;
bool led_state = false;

// How many milliseconds it has been since the last LED state change
int counter = 0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(2, INPUT);
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}
void loop() {

  // Check if the button was pressed
  if (digitalRead(2)){

    // If the button was pressed, wait half a second before toggling latch,
    // to "de-bounce" the button (prevent it from sending multiple clicks for
    // one press)
    delay(300);
    latch = !latch;
  }

  // If we are in on state (latch == true)...
  if (latch) {

    // ...add 1 to the counter and wait 1 millisecond...
    counter += 1;
    delay(1);

    // ...and toggle the LED state if 500 milliseconds have passed.
    // This we know because counter >= 500.
    if (counter >= 500) {
      if (led_state == true) led_state = false;
      else if (led_state == false) led_state = true;
      counter = 0;
    }
    digitalWrite(13, led_state);

  // If we are in off state, turn the LED off
  } else {
    digitalWrite(13, false);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I did some experimenting with a simulator similar to what i assume you setup is(use this to setup your situation for future Arduino questions to make it easier for people to understand and help)

https://wokwi.com/arduino/projects/312378906051084864

Besides adding a missing semi-colon here, and working with what i assume your knowledge of programming is

Before

```
}else{
  digitalWrite(13, LOW)
}
```

After

```
}else{
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);
}
```

I made the small change to your if statement and this makes it work with some specific uses you must tap the button to turn it on and hold it when you think the interval is about to expire. This is because of your use of the delay function which basically stops all execution of your program until the interval is over. So the pin associated with you button must be high after the delay intervals and during if latch is evaluated

```
if (digitalRead(1)){
  latch = true;
}else{
latch = false;
}
```

**RECOMMENDED ALTERNATIVE**

If you are interested in a better slightly more advance application of code i found this reference which provides a way to make a led blink without the use of the delay function

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BuiltInExamples/BlinkWithoutDelay